# how to display a site in a iframe in html

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

Why does this code not display the YouTube site or other sites like Pandora:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Open your browser's Developer console, and check the error

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that youtube doesn´t allow that way of access. Just with an embed code, like:

```
<html>
    <body><iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE" frameborder="0"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

This will work, but whole youtube can´t be embedded.

Have a nice day.